# Convert Python Array to String in List [Pandas]

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

**I want to convert pandas data frame from this:**

```
     label
0    ['hello', 'world']
1    ['just','string']
```

**To this:**

```
0   hello world
1   just string
```

**But, my output like this:**

```
0   [ ' h e l l o ' , ' w o r l d ' ]
1   [ ' j u s t ' , ' s t r i n g ' ]
```

**This is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('testing.csv',nrows=578)

temp = []
comment = []
for i in data['comment_clean']:
    temp = ' '.join(i) 
    comment.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame(comment, columns=['comment_clean_append'])
print (df)
```

this is my dataframe
[image]

Comment: pls paste your csv file here in code-format

Comment: ,video_id,title,comment,label,comment_clean,comment_freq_token,comment_stemmed  0,PwwL10ZlE6g,Vaksin Covid-19 Siap Januari 2021,Vaksin tak berguna,-1,"['vaksin', 'berguna']",<FreqDist with 3 samples and 3 outcomes>,"['vaksin', 'guna']"

Comment: I think you might just need to remove the space in ' '.join(i)  to ''.join(i). Haven't tried it though so may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.join`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [["Hello","world"], ["just","string"]]})

df["col"] = df["col"].str.join(" ")
```

df is:

```
col
0   Hello world
1   just string
```

Comment: thanks for answering before, but my output still like this ```0   [ ' h e l l o   w o r l d ' ]
1   [ ' j u s t   s t r i n g ' ]```

Comment: there are still spaces between the characters

Comment: maybe you can give an example dataframe (like i did on the df = line), cause i don't have that problem.

Comment: I added it in the post

Comment: we need a reproducible "pd.DataFrame({"column" : [ ....] } )" so we can compare results properly.